# I am trying to consume the sabre web service "OTA_AirAvailLLS1.1.1RQ.wsdl" with valid credentials but i am encountering the following:

Tags: xml, web-services, soap, sabre

"OTA_AirAvailLLS1.1.1RQ.wsd" sabre web service is throwing me the following error
when i point to development environment(https://sws3-sts.cert. sabre.com) of sabre, the "http://webservices.sabre.com/wsdl/sabreXML1.0.00/tpf/OTA_AirAvailLLS1.1.1RQ.wsdl" web service is throwing me the following error:

Exception Message : Invalid URI: The hostname could not be parsed.

Exception Stack Trace : at System.Uri.CreateThis(String uri, Boolean dontEscape, UriKind uriKind) at System.Uri..ctor(String uriString) at System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebClientProtocol.set_Url(String value) at OTA_AirAvailService..ctor() in c:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\WebSites\SabreWS\App_Code\sabre web services proxy\OTA_AirAvailLLS1RQProxy.cs:line 43 at _Default.btn3_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\WebSites\SabreWS\Default.aspx.cs:line 381

Comment: Please help me in resolving this error. Thanks in advance

Comment: and when point to "https://webservices.sabre.com/websvc" environment, its throwing the following: error:Response of OTA_AirAvail Service
Error : ÂFORMATÂ

Comment: FY-All-Info: Response of OTA_AirAvail Service
Error : ÂFORMATÂ
Error ErrorMessage: TPFAE:tpfc_liberty_lbthlp236.sabre.com_11010:60 2017-04-09 01:15:03
Error Severity: HIGH
Error ErrorCode: SessionFailure-103

Answer (score 0):

1. For the URL: https://sws3-sts.cert. sabre.com, there is an space in between. If you send a valid XML to a valid URL, you should get a valid XML in response, even if that is an error.
2. Instead of that URL you may try the other development URL found in the following link: https://developer.sabre.com/docs/read/soap_basics/environments
3. The error ÂFORMATÂ is a valid error, something in the request is missing or wrong.
4. If you are starting to develop, I would recommend you to do it with the latest version, as that might stop working when old version start to be deprecated. You may find the latest version in the resources page of the following link: https://developer.sabre.com/docs/read/soap_apis/air/search/Air_Availability